# MongoDB remove document and return it

Tags: mongodb

I would like to locate a document, remove it and also return it:

```
        tokens.col.remove({
            token: myTokenVar
        }, function (err, res) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); // <-- this results in null
        });
```

I'm wondering if I'm using the incorrect query type for this. Does MongoDB have such a method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible with another different command. Refer to [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) command. With the options to `{query: ..., remove: true, new: false}`, it will delete a single document and return the removed document.

Also there is one API [`findOneAndRemove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndRemove) in Mongoose, Finds a matching document, removes it, passing the found document (if any) to the callback.

Added by author: Also remove `.col`

```
        tokens.findAndModify({
            query: {
                token: myTokenVar
            },
            remove: true,
            new: false
        }, function (err, res) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        });
```